# Selection of first node of a tree is not happening with xtype treecolumn

Tags: ext4

I have created a tree panel by specifying the xtype as treecolumn. I want to select the first leaf of the tree. In this example I have registered the boxready event detailed below:

```
boxready : function( treePanel, width, height, eOpts ){

    treePanel.getSelectionModel().select( 0 );
    //treePanel.select( treePanel.getRootNode().getChildAt(0) );
    treePanel.getSelectionModel().selected = 0;
},
treePanel.getSelectionModel()
```

This example is giving me selectionmodel of type SINGLE.  Can anyone explain why my example does not select the first leaf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little "diagram":

If you need the leaf from beginning with:

- one node selected:

  var nodeData = treePanel.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
- from the begin:

  var node = treePanel.getRootNode(); -- father ( first Node );

  **findLeaf : function(node)**{

  ```
  if(node.isLeaf()){
  // this is the node that u want
  }else{
      // bucle to find it
      node.eachChild(function(nodeChild,array){
          if(nodeChild.isLeaf()){
             // this is the node that u want
          }else{
             // get childs of this node
             if(nodeChild.hasChildNodes()){
                  //find the childs from this node.
                  this.findLeaf(nodeChild);
             }
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  };

Comment: In my case there is no node selected, so  i got the node by 
var node = treePanel.getRootNode(); but inside the component i got childNodes of 0 items so it is not going to foreach loop. can you please tell me where am missing ?

Comment: If u didnt select one, you need to get the root node. Maybe, u can get it from the tree store.

but im thinking that ur store its empty, that the error...

Comment: Yes you are right. at that time time the store was empty. so i moved the code to store.onload, and now its working fine.